# How do I use C++ modules in Clang?

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, c++-modules

Modules are an alternative to #includes. [Clang has a complete implementation for C++](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2014/07/17/trip-report-c-standards-committee-meeting-in-rapperswil-june-2014/). How would I go about if I wanted to use modules using Clang now?

---

Using

```
import std.io;
```

in a C++ source file does not work (compile) yet, as the specification for modules (which includes syntax) isn't final.

---

The [Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#includes-as-imports) states that, when passing the `-fmodules` flag, #includes will be rewritten to their appropriate imports. However, checking the preprocessor suggests otherwise (test.cpp only contains `#include <stdio.h>` and an empty main):

```sh
$ clang++-3.5 -fmodules -E test.cpp -o test
$ grep " printf " test
extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);
```

Furthermore, compiling this test file with `-fmodules` vs no flags at all produces the same object file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like you mentioned, clang does not yet have a C++ syntax for imports, 
so I doubt that `#include` directives are going to be *literally* rewritten as imports when preprocessing a file, so that may not be the best way to test if modules are working as intended.

However, if you set `-fmodules-cache-path=<path>` explicitly, you can observe clang populating it with precompiled module files (*.pcm) during a build - if there are any modules involved.

You'll need to use libc++ (which seems to come with a module.modulemap as of version 3.7.0) if you want to use a modules enabled standard library right now - though in my experience this isn't working entirely just yet.
(Visual Studio 2015's C++ compiler is also supposed to get some form of module support with Update 1 in November)

Independently of the stdlib, you could still use modules in your own code. The clang docs contain a detailed description of the [Module Map Language](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#module-map-language).

Comment: It looks like your little example project is gone.. Any chance of updating this answer?

Comment: Modules and implementations have changed quite a bit in the last 5 years. Smi's answer reflects the current state much better, maybe @xjcl could change the accepted answer to that one.

Answer (score 36):

As of [this commit](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/commit/3ec1cdd422ec49d2a54ebc1a94d3d80ee57031c0), Clang has experimental support for the [Modules TS](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4720.pdf).

Let's take the same example files (with a small change) as in the [VS blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/03/c-modules-in-vs-2015-update-1/) about experimental module support.

First, define the module interface file. By default, Clang recognizes files with `cppm` extension (and some others) as C++ module interface files.

```
// file: foo.cppm
export module M;

export int f(int x)
{
    return 2 + x;
}
export double g(double y, int z)
{
    return y * z;
}
```

Note that the module interface declaration needs to be `export module M;` and not just `module M;` like in the VS blog post.

Then consume the module as follows:

```
// file: bar.cpp
import M;

int main()
{
    f(5);
    g(0.0, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, precompile the module `foo.cppm` with

```
clang++ -fmodules-ts --precompile foo.cppm -o M.pcm
```

or, if the module interface extension is other than `cppm` (let's say `ixx`, as it is with VS), you can use:

```
clang++ -fmodules-ts --precompile -x c++-module foo.ixx -o M.pcm
```

Then build the program with

```
clang++ -fmodules-ts -c M.pcm -o M.o
clang++ -fmodules-ts -fprebuilt-module-path=. M.o bar.cpp
```

or, if the pcm file name is not the same as the module name, you'd have to use:

```
clang++ -fmodules-ts -fmodule-file=M.pcm bar.cpp
```

I've tested these commands on Windows using the [r303050 build](http://llvm.org/pre-releases/win-snapshots/LLVM-5.0.0-r303050-win32.exe) (15th May 2017).

Note: When using the `-fprebuilt-module-path=.` option, I get a warning:

> clang++.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fprebuilt-module-path=.' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]

which appears to be incorrect because without that option, the module `M` is not found.

Comment: With these commands I get: `clang++ -fmodules-ts -fmodule-file=M.pcm bar.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "f(int)", referenced from:
      _main in bar-1b6ad3.o
  "g(double, int)", referenced from:
      _main in bar-1b6ad3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
`  with: ` clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`

Comment: EDIT: what was missing from this answer is an additional compile step `clang++ -fmodules-ts -c M.pcm -o M.o` followed by adding M.o to final compile step as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48596805/linking-c-modules-ts-using-clang/49322001#49322001 ; I fixed the answer

Comment: Can iostream be imported?

Comment: Recent versions of clang support `--std=c++20` which should be used in place of `-fmodules-ts` above.