# How to use VC++ modules in CMake

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, c++-modules

MS Visual C++ 2015 Update 1 [implements the Modules proposal](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/03/c-modules-in-vs-2015-update-1/).

Here is an example of how it works:
Sources:

```
// c.ixx             |  // b.ixx                   |  // a.cpp
module GM;           |  import GM;                 |  import FM;
export void g() {}   |  module FM;                 |  int main() { f(); }
                     |  export void f() { g(); }   |
```

Build commands:

```
set CL=/EHsc /experimental:module   # Default flags for cl.exe
cl.exe /c c.ixx                     # Produces c.obj, GM.ifc
cl.exe /c b.ixx                     # Depends on GM.ifc, produces b.obj, FM.ifc
cl.exe /c a.cpp                     # Depends on FM.ifc, produces a.obj
link.exe a.obj b.obj c.obj          # Produces a.exe
```

Dependency graph:

```
c.ixx → GM.ifc → b.ixx → FM.ifc → a.cpp
     ↘            ↓             ↙
       c.obj     b.obj    a.obj
            ↘     ↓      ↙
                 a.exe
```

Each module has one `file.ixx` with its exports.
This file will be compiled into `ModuleName.ifc` and `file.obj`.

If a file imports module `M`, a `M.ifc` file must be present.
By default cl.exe searches `.ifc` files in current directory, but it's possible to specify explicit names or search path:

```
cl.exe /c a.cpp
-- or --
cl.exe /c a.cpp /module:reference FM.ifc
-- or --
cl.exe /c a.cpp /module:search ./
```

So, the question is: **How to use the VC++ implementation of modules in CMake**?
It's not necessary to use the MSBuild backend, Ninja is fine too.

Comment: So, what is a problem to combine commands `add_custom_command`, which have appropriate OUTPUT and DEPENDS parts, with `add_custom_target` (or even `add_executable`, which can consume pre-created object files)? Or you want **automatic** resolving dependencies between modules?

Comment: Seems like CLang will need to be the toolchain of choice, not GCC. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307657/how-do-i-use-modules-in-clang At least I haven't been able to find any mention of GCC support for C++ modules.

Comment: please note that cl supports hyphens as switch character

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe anyone has done any build system work for C++ modules at this time. It's likely we (Microsoft) will do MSBuild support first, but CMake is definitely a possibility.

Comment: As you know, cmake is a generator and, afaik, supports two directly-executable back-ends: various makefile variants, and ninja. The other generators bring yet another level of indirection before you can execute anything. The "problem" with C++ modules as they are currently being standardised is that it's going to be *very* arcane to support them with those back-ends.