# Purpose of "import std;" in C++

Tags: c++, c++-modules

I have seen following small piece of code on [cppdepend](http://cppdepend.com/blog/?p=228) site.

```
import std; // Module import directive.

int main() 
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World\n";
}
```

So, What is the purpose of `import std;` in C++? How to use `import std;` instead of `using namespace std;` in C++?

I tried to compile program in **G++** compiler, but I got an error.

Comment: ***What is the purpose of import std; C++? How to use import std; instead of using namespace std;*** They are completely different concepts. import is about c++ modules.

Comment: "here’s an example from the C++0x draft" - the feature never got to C++11 in the first place. About what it's supposed to do: the page you linked to explains well enough

Comment: not an exact duplicate, but certainly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307657/how-do-i-use-c-modules-in-clang

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So, What is the purpose of import std; C++?

Its purpose is to make names from the `std` module available. Modules are a language feature that has been proposed for inclusion in a future C++ standard.

> How to use `import std;` instead of using `namespace std;` in C++?

They are not exclusive so you cannot use one *instead* of another. Namespaces are a separate language feature from modules. You can use both, either or neither.

> I tried to compile program in G++ compiler, but I got an error.

Considering that the hypothetical future standard version is not yet released, nor is it even decided that modules would definitely be part of a future standard, it's hardly surprising that a compiler hasn't implemented them.

You can find the state of modules in GCC here: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-modules
At the moment of writing, work has begun and is underway on a development branch.