# Linking C++ modules TS using clang

Tags: c++, clang, c++-modules

I'm trying to use C++ modules TS with clang.

I've created two files:

```
// foo.cppm
export module foo;

export void test() {
}
```

and

```
// bar.cpp
import foo;

int main() {
  test();
  return 0;
}
```

I compile `foo.cppm` with this command

```
clang++ --std=c++17 -fmodules-ts --precompile foo.cppm -o foo.pcm
```

It compiles without an error and creates a `foo.pcm` file, but when i try to compile a binary with this command:

```
clang++ --std=c++17 -fmodules-ts -fprebuilt-module-path=. -fmodule-file=foo.pcm bar.cpp
```

it prints an error:

```
/tmp/bar-f69a1f.o: In function `main':
bar.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `test()'
```

I tried it with clang 7 trunk and clang 6.
Also i tried different `std` options and this command:

```
clang++ --std=c++17 -fmodules-ts -fmodule-file=foo.pcm bar.cpp -o bar
```

And nothing helps.

Interesting enough that if one module uses symbols from other, clang compiles these modules. So as i understand the problem is in linking stage.

What can be a problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like what https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/03/c-modules-in-vs-2015-update-1/ says, .cppm (.ixx) translates to .pcm (.ifc) **and** .o (.obj).

But unlike cl.exe, which automatically produce these two files, Clang's .o file must be compiled from its .pcm file:

```
clang++ --std=c++17 -fmodules-ts -c foo.pcm -o foo.o
```

With `foo.cppm` and `bar.cpp` above, the commands would be like:

```
clang++ --std=c++17 -fmodules-ts --precompile foo.cppm -o foo.pcm
clang++ --std=c++17 -fmodules-ts -c foo.pcm -o foo.o
clang++ --std=c++17 -fmodules-ts -fprebuilt-module-path=. foo.o bar.cpp
```

Comment: i tested it with clang++ 7.0.0 trunk x64-pc-linux-gnu and report that it works, thank you!

Comment: Indeed. It seems that -fmodule-file=foo.pcm must not be used to generate your final executable (with main). However, I noticed that to generate intermediate module files (module that depends on another module), it is imperative to use -fmodule-file=dependency.pcm as just adding dependency.pcm besides other source files will make clang++ think it's a normal source and that it needs to generate two object files (one per source), causing -o to fail (clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files). This seems to be a clang bug as without -o, it produces a correct foo.o...

Comment: ... which can be renamed foo.pcm and perfectly work for the final compilation step!

Answer (score 0):

In the producing module (foo.cppm) you need to omit the keyword `export` from the module definition.

```
// foo.cppm
module foo;

export void test() {
}
```

Everything else should work fine.

Comment: clang prints `error: missing 'export' specifier in module declaration while building module interface`

Comment: Funny - which clang and which OS are you using? My clang does not support commandline option --std=c++17 but everything else did work nicely (Mac OS)

Comment: I'm trying to compile with clang 6.0 and clang 7.0 on Debian Linux 9.3