# how to use standard library with C++ modules? (eg: `import std.io`)

Tags: c++, clang, std, standard-library, c++-modules

The basic example given in [How do I use C++ modules in Clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307657/how-do-i-use-c-modules-in-clang) works for me but doesn't import the standard library (eg via `import std.stdio;`); after going over http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html it wasn't clear how to use the standard library in a C++ module, eg:

```
// foo.cppm:
export module foo;
// works: #include <stdio.h>
// none of these work:
import std.stdio;
import std.io;
import std;

export void test_foo(){
  printf("hello world\n");
}
```

this gives an error:

`clang++ -std=c++17 -fmodules-ts --precompile foo.cppm -o foo.pcm
foo.cppm:4:8: fatal error: module 'std.stdio' not found`

NOTE:

`clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0`

I'm on OSX.
I also tried clang from brew install llvm and also didn't work.

What's the simplest way to make something like this work?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/search?l=C%2B%2B&p=1&q=import&type=) are a few examples of `import` being used within clang if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Clang does not currently support `import std.io` syntax in C or C++.

From clang's [module documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#objective-c-import-declaration):

> At present, there is no C or C++ syntax for import declarations. Clang will track the modules proposal in the C++ committee. See the section 'Includes as imports' to see how modules get imported today.

When you pass the `-fmodules` flag, `#include` statements are automatically translated to `import`.

From the [Includes as imports](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#includes-as-imports) section:

> modules automatically translate #include directives into the corresponding module import. For example, the include directive
>
> `#include <stdio.h>`
>
> will be automatically mapped to an import of the module std.io.

Comment: the snippet you mention (`At present, there is no C or C++ syntax for import declarations`) is from paragraph on `Objective-C Import declaration` so I don't think it's relevant to this question; `module foo` definitely works as I mentioned in the OP; my question was more about how to use standard library rather than the language feature of `import` (which *are* supported, even if only via experimental flag)

Comment: I took it to mean Objective-C is the only language with import declaration support in clang. The only other thing I saw in the documentation about C/C++ was that `#include` is automatically mapped to  the corresponding `import` when the module flag is included.

Comment: It looks like clang does support `import` within C++. I found some examples of `import` being used within clang [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/search?l=C%2B%2B&p=1&q=import&type=).