# import keywords are not recognized by clang with modules

Tags: c++, module, clang

I am trying to bring a simple Hello World example with modules to work. Can anyone help me what I a missing here? Clang doesn't seem to recognize the corresponding import keywords

```
clang++ -fmodules -std=c++17 -fbuiltin-module-map
```

Any idea is highly appreciated:

```
#include <iostream>
import std;
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    return 0;
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/c1ejGC

```
error: unknown type name 'import'
```

To be on the safe side, I tried this on the trunk version of clang

```
clang version 8.0.0 (trunk 343649)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Comment: This was already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683282/how-to-use-standard-library-with-c-modules-eg-import-std-io) a while back

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use standard library with C++ modules? (eg: \`import std.io\`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683282/how-to-use-standard-library-with-c-modules-eg-import-std-io)

Comment: The posts relate to the fact that std.io is not supported. In my case I can't get it to work with any module. As far as I understand their documentation it means `#include <iostream>` becomes `import iostream;` which doesn't work either